# HTC G2 Phone randomly turns off w fully charged battery on Gingerbread 2.3

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, battery, power-on

My HTC G2 running Android Gingerbread 2.3 randomly turns off while running applications such as the camera with full battery. After the random turn off I try to turn the phone on again and it won't turn on. I have to physically remove the battery, wait 30 seconds, put it back in, and turn on the phone to finally get it to work.

Is there an app to prevent this or software update or do I need a new battery?

PS: My previous phone, the Motorola Cliq w/ Android 2.1 and Motoblur also had this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known hardware issue with the HTC G2. Mine used to be hung at a black screen randomly when I tried to turn the screen on and unlock it. If your warranty hasn't already expired, start the process to get a replacement. The replacement I got hasn't experienced any of those issues.

Comment: thanks for your reply! how long is the warranty? How do i check to see if i still have it?

Comment: @BrianMcCarthy It's probably in the original package. But I'd just call your provider (T-Mobile?). They'll know.